# Can you set the text based on the application user chooses to share with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

So for example, if the user wants to share with twitter, the text would be different than if a user chooses to share with email.

How would I code that with initWithActivityItems?:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `objectsToShare`, supply an object that adopts the UIActivityItemSource protocol. This protocol means your object will be called with `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:`. The second parameter that tells you the activity type. Thus you can return a different item, depending on the activity type.