# Change activity items base on which application is selected for sharing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, share

I share an image with text to othe applications.

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[title, finalImage];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Problem with this code is that I share title and image for all destination apps. but for instance, WhatsApp has problem when I share image with title. When I delete title it will correctly share the image but when I add title to activityItems, it just sends title. I want to detect if whats app is selected and then just send the image

Comment: @matt Thanks. Could you explain a little more

Comment: See for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296314/can-you-set-the-text-based-on-the-application-user-chooses-to-share-with-uiactiv